# Allowing redirection of StandardInput of a C# application when doing "Console.ReadKey"

Tags: c#, .net, redirect, input, console

I have 2 applications, A & B.

- A calls B within a Process.
- B do some stuffs like Console.WriteLine and Console.ReadLine
- Thanks to this [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline.aspx), I manage somehow to redirect the output of B and to feed its input as well.
- **What I don't manage to do**, is to have the **Console.ReadKey** function in B work. I made a try catch block arround this function and I got this error message:

> *Cannot read keys when either application does not have a console, or when console input has been redirected from a file. Try Console.Read*

The fact is, I have to use Console.ReadKey, so I need to find a way to make it work...Any idea?

Here are the useful parts of the code of A

---

In the Main function:

```
Process P2 = new Process();
P2.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Main2.exe";
P2.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
P2.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
P2.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(WriteOutput);
P2.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
P2.Start();
StreamWriter ExeInput = P2.StandardInput;
P2.BeginOutputReadLine();
ConsoleKeyInfo KeyPressed;
do 
{
    KeyPressed = Console.ReadKey();
    if(KeyPressed.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ();
        ExeInput.Write("\n");
    }
    else
        ExeInput.Write(KeyPressed.KeyChar);
} while (!P2.HasExited);
```

---

The handler for outputdatareceived:

```
private static void WriteOutput(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data))

    {
        Console.WriteLine(outLine.Data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to see if this article is useful for you: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/less_command.aspx . Actually it doesn't use `Process` class but shows a way of calling Console.ReadKey() when doing this kind of things.

Comment: Your question appears to ask for a solution that violates a dcoumented constraint. You can't use ReadKey. The documentation says so. Move on to a solution that does work.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not aware of any way of being able to use `ReadKey()` when redirecting the StdIn/StdOut of a console program.  Furthermore, in order to read and write from the child process, you need to make sure you're using `Console.Out.Write()`/`Console.In.Read()` to prevent exceptions from being thrown from the child process, because it is lacking a console window.

You can use `Convert.ToChar(ExeOutput.Read())` to convert the input to a valid `KeyChar`, mimicing the behavior of `ReadKey()`  Also keep in mind Synchronous vs Asynchronous reads/writes.  If you use `BeginOutputReadLine()` and read the stream Asynchronously, your while condition of P2.HasExited may become true before you read all of the input keys when using `ExeOutput.Read()`

```
        .....
        P2.Start();
        StreamWriter ExeInput = P2.StandardInput;
        StreamReader ExeOutput = P2.StandardOutput;
        do
        {
            var k = P2.StandardOutput.Read();
            var key = Convert.ToChar(k);
            if (key == Convert.ToChar(ConsoleKey.Enter))
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                ExeInput.Write("\n");
            }
            else
                ExeInput.Write(key);
        } while (!P2.HasExited);
        ....
```

Fortunately, the streams will be buffered if the process has exited before you've read every line, so you may consider changing the condition to `while(!P2.HasExited && !P2.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)` if that fits what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I assume you wanted to say var k = Console.In.Read(); Well it works a bit better with Console.In.Read indeed, thanks; but I still don't get to have Console.ReadKey of B work...

Comment: You can't use Console.ReadKey in B.  You have to use Console.In.Read() and do the same code as above.

Comment: `Console.In.Read` doesn't return until user enter whole line, while `Console.ReadKey` returns immediately as soon as user enter any key. Any safe method of reading from redirected input stream while being able to read individual keystrokes as soon as they are typed in?