# System.TypeInitializationException between two program in F#

Tags: exception, f#

I'm working on a project and I become always an Exception "TypeInitializationException".
I tried to give a string to a global string variable but it failed.
That's the code for the viewmodel and it failed on the second line

```
| {State = _}, ConsumablesClicked vm ->
    Testtyp <- vm.TrackPosition.ToString()
```

That's on the other program

```
let mutable Testtyp = ""
```

I become this InnerException "Cannot read keys when either application does not have a console or when console input has been redirected from a file. Try Console.Read.".

"The type initializer for '.$BarcodeGenerieren' threw an exception.", that's the exception explication.

Has someone a Idea how solve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution after a lot of try and it was only, that I had a Console.Readkey in my code, that I forgot to delete.

I had before a console apllication and I transformed it to be a class.

Answer (score 1):

That exception indicates that some code is trying to call `Console.ReadKey` when the standard input for that process has been redirected (see e.g. [Allowing redirection of StandardInput of a C# application when doing "Console.ReadKey"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880624/allowing-redirection-of-standardinput-of-a-c-sharp-application-when-doing-conso)).  The solution is not to call `Console.ReadKey`, but it's not clear from your description where this is actually happening (perhaps in the static constructor for one of your types?).