# How to provide Console input to when running Linqpad?

Tags: linqpad, linqpad5

Within LinqPad I can use things like

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

OR

```
Util.ReadLine();
```

But how do you run these in such a way you can actually enter the input?

The UI doesn't have a console window!

Comment: A black bar will appear at the bottom of the output window and you type into it. `ReadKey` can't be used, but `Read` or `ReadLine` work.

Comment: ReadKey does not work in LINQPad because ReadKey cannot be redirected: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880624/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using `Util.ReadLine()` gives you a black box at the bottom of the window to input your...input

[image]